# Finding the exact word exist

Tags: bash, macos, zsh, shebang

I just started using dockutil and what to write a script that does the following.

Checks if the item exists on the dock. if it doesn't exist add it. if it does do nothing.

so do to check if item exist you can use the following command

```
~ % dockutil --find Keynote
```

The results would echo back with the following

```
Keynote was not found in Keynote was not found in /Users/$UserName/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist
```

So I wrote the following script to capture the input

```
 app='Keynote'
echo "${app}"


Test=$(dockutil --find "${app}" | tr ' ' '\n'| grep "not")

  if [[ ${Test} == "not" ]]; then

  echo " its not there "

else

  echo "its there"

fi
```

The problem is Keynote has the word "not" in its name which will always give me a false positive.
Is there a way to look for "not found" or even just "not" from the results.  Or maybe even another way of doing the if statement all together.

Comment: `grep "not found"` ?

Comment: Does `dockutil` not set its exit status? File that as a bug if it doesn't. If it _does_ behave like a good UNIX tool and set exit status to indicate success/failure you should be able to just use `if dockutil --find "$app" >/dev/null 2>&1; then ...` and not have any need to read or parse its output at all.

Comment: Also, even if `dockutil` doesn't, `grep` sets exit status so there's no reason to have a `Test` variable. `if dockutil --find "$app" | grep -qE 'was not found in'; then echo "its not there"; else echo "its there"; fi`

Comment: Did the first approach (without grep) work, or did you have to use the second?

Comment: The immediate problem with your attempt is that `Test` will never be exactly equal to the string `"not"`. To search for a substring, `[ "$Test" = *"not"* ]`; but, as indicated above, examining the exit status is much preferred (the output might be in a different language if the user is in a non-English locale, or the program could be updated to make trivial changes to its output strings). (Also, the `tr` is pretty useless there; the shell can accommodate multi-line strings just fine.)

Comment: Your script cannot be both a [tag:zsh] script and a [tag:bash] script at the same time, but your question does not reveal which one you are using, and the script doesn't have a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). Probably moot now, but goig forward, probably read [Difference between Bash and `sh`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash) and perhaps find a similar resource about the differences between Bash and Zsh.

Answer (score 1):

`dockutil` exits with 1 if the item is not found, then you can do

```
app='Keynote'
echo "${app}"


if ! dockutil --find "${app}"; then
    echo " its not there "
fi
```

Comment: The curlies around `${app}` are not really useful here.

Comment: harmless and not helpful either